# Is there a way to retain the phone numbers with + sign format when exporting to Excel/CSV

Tags: excel, excel-formula, salesforce

I noticed that anytime I export from somewhere like Salesforce where the Phone = `+123124141`.

The data in Excel will just become `=123124141` or #NAME? or some other Error spouted from Excel.

This makes data patch extremely painful and manual. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Before you open the CSV file in Excel, open in a text editor and do a global search and replace. Replace the `+` with `'+`

Comment: Do the above, save the changes, and then open in Excel and you will have the plus symbols display... while the apostrophes won't.

Comment: Were you able to make this work? This methond works well.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the file, use a different extension than .csv or .txt (these ones are interpreted by EXCEL as a green light to interpret columns as numeric/date, etc and format accordingly. Use .DAT, for example. When you open it from within EXCEL it will invoke the text import wizard, and there you should choose comma separated (or tab separated, etc, as the case maybe), and on the final screen of the wizard, choose the columns you don't want reformatted (you can choose all of them, if you like), and choose Text. Now the column values will be kept intact.

Alternatively you can first create a blank workbook/sheet, and use Data From Text to invoke the Wizard and bring the data in the same way.

If you don't want EXCEL to launch and open when you double-click on a .CSV file, without asking questions, you can remove the file-association (of CSV with EXCEL) using Windows explorer.

It is reasonably easy to develop a VBA macro to import such delimited files using 'TEXT' data types to automate what the Wizard would do.

Comment: Wow! How about those using a Macbook without Excel installed? Wonder if .DAT can work for mac also haha.

Comment: @comspki, your question tags EXCEL. I don't know what application is associated with DAT extension in a Mac, but similar  concepts apply.